# Excel - VBA Macro - Stopping code at a specific sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a number of sheets with the same template where I want to sort the date field. I've been doing it manually but am trying VBA to do it for me. I have the code below which works but it applies to more sheets than I'd like. I am trying to figure out how to stop the macro to stop at a specific sheet and end it there.

Goal: have macro run from sheet 1-10, stop @ sheet 10 or if worksheet = Sheet 11 then stop. I am using sheet 1-10, 11 as simple references. I'd insert the specific sheet name.

I found some answers online with -

```
If ws.Name <> "" Then
end with
```

but am not sure where to input it within my macro below.

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' sortbydate2 Macro
'

'
Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

    With ws
        With .Sort
            .SortFields.Clear
            .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A2:a49"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
            .SetRange ws.Cells
            .Header = xlYes
            .MatchCase = False
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
            .SortMethod = xlPinYin
            .Apply
        End With
    End With
Next ws
End Sub
```

Thank you,
P1

Comment: Thank you for all your answers. will give it a shot shortly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Manipulate All Worksheets Except...

- You can implement an 'exceptions array' where you would preferably
  place the **names**, or the indexes (not recommended) of the unwanted
  worksheets.
- Then you can use `IsError` with `Application.Match` to check if the name of the current worksheet has been found in the 'exceptions array'.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Macro1()
'
' sortbydate2 Macro
'

'
    Dim Exceptions As Variant
    Exceptions = Array("Sheet11", "Sheet12") ' add more or less.
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If IsError(Application.Match(ws.Name, Exceptions, 0)) Then
            With ws
                With .Sort
                    .SortFields.Clear
                    .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A2:a49"), _
                                    SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
                                    Order:=xlAscending, _
                                    DataOption:=xlSortNormal
                    .SetRange ws.Cells
                    .Header = xlYes
                    .MatchCase = False
                    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
                    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
                    .Apply
                End With
            End With
        End If
    Next ws

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You could loop through all worksheets within the workbook and apply the filter to all except - something like:

```
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
      if ws.Name <> "IDontWantFilters" Then
          with ws
            ....
          end with
     end if
next ws
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work. I assume once it gets to sheet11 you just want it to stop completly

```
Sub Macro1()


Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

    if ws.name = "Sheet11" then
        exit sub
    end if

    With ws
        
        With .Sort
            .SortFields.Clear
            .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A2:a49"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
            .SetRange ws.Cells
            .Header = xlYes
            .MatchCase = False
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
            .SortMethod = xlPinYin
            .Apply
        End With
    End With
Next ws
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to sort the first 10 worksheets, you could do a basic loop to accomplish your task...

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
For i = 1 To 10
    Set ws = Sheets(i)
        
    With ws.Sort
        .SortFields.Clear
        .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A2:A49"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .SetRange Sheets(i).Cells
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
Next i
```